# ¿Como se llama el evento de mantener pulsado un item en Android studio?

Tags: android, eventos

Tengo un listview y quiero que al mantener presionado por unos segundos un item se depliegue un dialog con varias opciones, alguien me podria asesorar como se llama este tipo de eventos.
Gracias.

Comment: una pulsación larga?

Comment: Exactamente, si una pulsación normal equivale a OnClickListener una pulsación larga a que evento se refiere?

Comment: se refiere a onLongClick, ahora subo un ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para detectar una pulsación larga sobre un elemento, se debe lanzar un listener `setOnLongClickListener` sobre el elemento, para captura el evento `onLongClick`.

```
tv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //Pulsación larga
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfecto parce, era lo que buscaba muchas gracias.